# How to restore oozie/sqoop logs in Hue on EMR once cluster it terminated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sqoop, oozie, emr, hue

So we are planing to use a EMR which will be up for some hours in a day process data and the cluster will be terminated once processing is done.

On a regular cloudera installation(or Hortonworks), when we run a oozie job, we can clearly see the logs in Hue and they are saved somewhere. 
So is there a way on EMR where we can save these logs to s3 and once the new cluster is up and running, plug these saved logs back from s3 into the Hue on the new cluster.

Please advise

Comment: That "somewhere" might be the SQL database that Oozie uses as back-end. Not sure whether EMR starts a dummy DerbyDB instance by default, or uses a more robust solution (i.e. MySQL or PostgreSQL). So now you've got to find out the exact technology, the exact connection parameters to reach that DB directly, and finally a way to dump the DB contents somewhere before your cluster terminates.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Amazon EMR clusters launched using the console automatically archive log files to Amazon S3. You can specify your own log path, or you can allow the console to automatically generate a log path for you.

Almost all logs in /mnt/var/log/ directory of all EMR nodes will be continuously pushed to S3 for persistent storage. This includes application logs such as OOZIE/ SQOOP.

The s3 prefix for applications should be like

**OOZIE** : `/j-3GL0155VMY123/node/i-f0954123/applications/oozie/`

```
catalina.2016-11-15.log.gz
catalina.out.gz
derby.log.gz
oozie-error.log.gz
oozie-instrumentation.log.gz
oozie-jpa.log.gz
oozie-ops.log.gz
oozie.log.gz
```

Where j-3GL0155VMY123 is EMR cluster-id , i-f0954123 is the instance-id of master/core.

If you are concerned about container logs  , then you can look at the `/j-3GL0155VMY123/containers/` prefix.